# Autoplay Play Promise with YouTube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, html5-video

With the [recent changes to how Chrome autoplays videos](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes), I'm trying to determine if there is a way to have a play promise for an autoplaying iframe, more specifically the YouTube API.

Currently, I'm using this code for HTML5 `<video>`'s:

```
var promise = $( 'video' ).get(0).play();

if (promise !== undefined) {
  promise.then(_ => {
    // Autoplay started!
  }).catch(error => {
    // Autoplay was prevented.
  });
}
```

But if I'm using the YouTube API, I can not get the video object. I tried the code below, but it won't work due to no object.

```
var promise = YTPlayer.playVideo()
```

Does anyone have any recommendations or know if this is even possible at the moment?

Thanks!

Comment: Same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080974/detect-youtube-iframe-autoplay-failure

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994016/youtube-api-detect-if-autoplay-is-disabled

Comment: Did you find a solution? running into the same issue.